# Issue with assigning HRESULT using CoInitializeEx

Tags: c++, com, hresult

I am trying to use Microsoft's tutorial here to set up a COM connection for WMI programming. I have slightly modified the example code to fit my style. My code so far is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WbemIdl.h>

#define _WIN32_DCOM

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemidl.lib")

HRESULT hRes;
hRes = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

if(FAILED(hRes)) 
{
    std::cout << "COM initializtion failed." << std::endl;
}
```

My issue appears on the assignment at:

```
hRes = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
```

I see a little red squiggly, so I check it and it says:

[image: Error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier]

I have no idea what the issue is I haven't really done C++ in a while, so I could me just making a dumb mistake. Some Googling lead me to an SO question that said that the type was not defined because the correct header had not been included, but (please correct me if I'm wrong on this) I thought that `HRESULT` was defined in `Windows.h`.

Can anyone see an issue with this code? It is a Win32 console application and I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You seem to be trying to put statements outside of a function? You can't do that in C++. All code that does anything must be inside a function.

Comment: @immibis "_You can't do that in C++_" Actually you can do it in rudimentary forms :-). Consider `HRESULT hRes = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code has to go inside a function..

```
HRESULT hRes;
hRes = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

if(FAILED(hRes)) 
{
    std::cout << "COM initializtion failed." << std::endl;
}
```

You can't write code outside function. You can write declarations but not the code itself, precisely that's what error `*This declaration has no storage class or type specifier*` states.